# Manual custom script partially working.

Tags: export, magento-1.9

I need to export my target path and request path url's of my products and categories.

custom code :

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$data=Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getCollection();

$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w+');
$csvHeader = array('request_psth',"target_path");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($fp, array($row->getData('request_path'),$row->getData('target_path')), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Its working in my localhost, and i get export file, when i try to applied on hosting site, its not working.**

i have post my code via ftp, like

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtzWT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the product to the magento root directory, then only it will work as it is including Mage.php.

Also make sure your file has enough permission to execute. Once you uploaded the file using ftp, change the permission by

> **Right click** on the file, select **File permissions** type **755** in the text field

Comment: How did you try to execute the script?

Comment: past in root folder, then execute, url/filename.php

Comment: Share few screenshots: the permission of the script, directory to which you pasted and what the browser output etc